# Multiple iterations by index inside nested ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor

I use trackByIndex function for iterate items inside ngFor loops:

```
trackByIndex(index: number, obj: any): any {
  return index;
}
```

Here is a short example with my code how i want use it:

```
<div *ngFor="let comment of comments; let i = index; trackBy: trackByIndex">
  {{ i, comment.text }}
  <div *ngFor="let answer of comment.answers; let j = index; trackBy: trackByIndex">{{ j, answer.text }}</div>
</div>
```

But when i have 2 `comment` items on my page, i have answers with same iteration inside every comment:

```
"comment 1": {
    "answer 1",
    "answer 2"
},
"comment 2": {
    "answer 1", // should be answer 3
    "answer 2" // should be answer 4
}
```

How can i solved this? Huge thanks for any tips.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think, You have missed the binding of ngFor

Try to use

```
<div *ngFor="let comment of comments; let i = index; trackBy: trackByIndex">
  {{ i, comment.text }}
  <div *ngFor="let answer of comment.answers; let j = index; trackBy: trackByIndex">{{ j, answer.text }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not see any difference from what I wrote in question

Comment: your wrote comments.answers, but it should be comment.answers;

Comment: comments is the array, you can not write by this way comments.answers

Comment: yes, my fault. in real code i do it right. problem is not about this.